# Problem installing phpimage for TinyMCE

Tags: php, image, tinymce

Hay all, this is really bugging me.

I have downloaded phpimage from http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2844769&group_id=103281&atid=738747

I've decompressed the zip file and moved the "phpimage" folder into my "plugins" folder. 
In my settings i've added "phpimage" to the "plugins" setting so it reads

```
plugins : " safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,phpimage,",
```

And i've added the "phpimage" to the "theme_advanced_buttons1" settings, this looks like

```
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "phpimage,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink,anchor",
```

when i load the editor up it reveals a blank textarea. If i remove the phpimage from the plugins setting the textarea appears as the TinyMCE.

Any ideas? Firebug isn't giving too much help.

Comment: yepp, it is not working (even though i removed the trailing comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing i discovered is if you load tinymce using the developer mode (tiny_mce_dev) the file editor_plugin_src.js is missing. You can correct this by copying the file editor_plugin.js and rename it to editor_plugin_src.js.

This comment of KOPFteam at SF helped me make it work at last. It was the langauge file!!
My langugage setting is "de", so after creating a file under langs called de.js it worked like a charm and the editor was back. **What is your language setting?**. I suggest you name it according to this setting. Here KOPFteam's comment:

> It's up and running in German!
>
> It took me a few hours to sort out a
>   few problems:
>
> 1) I uploaded the phpimage folder into
>   the tiny_mce/plugins folder, created
>   an image upload folder, entered
>   "phpimage" twice into my tinyMCE.init
>   and - no tinyMCE anymore. Pure HTML.
>   What happened? I checked the Webserver
>   ErrorLog where a "file
>   ...../phpimage/lang/de.js missing"
>   shows. I have no idea why it is
>   looking for that file. I hadn't
>   changed /phpimage/config.php at that
>   point. So I duplicated the file
>   /phpimage/lang/en_dlg.js and renamed
>   it to de.js and suddenly tinyMCE is
>   back! And the phpimage button works -
>   with the dialog in English. 2) Next I
>   tried to upload an image. I got an
>   alert that an folder cannot be created
>   (I forgot the exact text). I solved
>   that by editing /phpimage/config.php
>   by adding a fifth "/.." to the
>   definition of $_cur_dir. After that
>   uploading of images worked. 3) Because
>   I found it on the authors website, I
>   uploaded the file
>   /phpimage/classes/lang/class.upload.lang.de_DE.php
>   and than changed the $language
>   parameter in /phpimage/config.php to
>   de_DE. After that I duplicated the
>   file /phpimage/lang/en_dlg.js again.
>   This time I renamed the copy to
>   de_dlg.js and translated the content
>   of that file to German. And after
>   that: a working dilaog with german
>   lables! BTW: German Umlauts can be
>   used by inserting the 4 digit unicode
>   value as in "Bild
>   einf\u00FCgen/bearbeiten" 4)After
>   uploading a modified file to my
>   webserver I had to quit and restart
>   Firefox. Simply reloading nstill
>   showed the old file.